# Notice: Undefined offset: 0 foreach

Tags: php, for-loop

I am trying to get response via API and store it in DB

```
print_r($result_arr);
//is printing all the data and my next line is 
foreach ($result_arr[0]["http_response_body"]["Items"] as $key => $value) {
```

this is giving error

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\index.php on line
>   33 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in 
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\api\index.php on line 33

API response I get is

```
Array ( [Items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [SKU] => 123 [Quantity] => 13 
[ProductName] => tet prod [Description] => blah blah ...
```

Comment: @MickaelLeger now it shows Notice: Undefined index: http_response_body in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\index.php on line 33

Comment: Can you show what `print_r($result_arr);` looks like? (I deleted my last comment, bad reading !)

Comment: This is how it looks like Array ( [Items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [SKU] => 123 [Quantity] => 13 
[ProductName] => tet prod [Description] => blah blah ...  and keeps going on I have about 200 records

Comment: OK, so just try `foreach ($result_arr["Items"] as $key => $value) {` no?

Comment: Yes this works. Thanks

Comment: Nice, I post the anwser tho :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you got :

```
print_r($result_arr);
```

This give you this array :

```
Array ( 
    [Items] => 
        Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
                [SKU] => 123 
                [Quantity] => 13 
                [ProductName] => tet prod 
                [Description] => blah blah ...
```

And this is what you do :

```
foreach ($result_arr[0]["http_response_body"]["Items"] as $key => $value) {
```

You get `Notice: Undefined offset: 0`just because as you can see there is no `$result_arr[0]` in your array.

So just do :

```
foreach ($result_arr["Items"] as $key => $value) {
```

And it should works !

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The API response you are getting the multi-dimentional array with three nested level.

The correct way to access is

```
foreach($result_arr as $key=>$val)
{
   print_r($val); // this line for reference prints [0] array elements
   foreach($val as $key1=>$val1)
   {
        echo $val1['SKU']; // prints 123
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your array has been built like this:

```
$result_arr["Items"][] = array( "sku"=>123, "qty" => 44, "ProductName" => "tet prod", "Description" => "blahh" );
```

you can iterate through this array like:

```
foreach ($result_arr["Items"] as $key => $value) {
    echo "key: " . $key . ", sku:" . $value["sku"] . ", prod:" . $value[ "ProductName" ] . "<br />";
}

foreach ($result_arr["Items"] as $items ) {
    foreach( $items as $key => $value ) {
        echo $key . "/" . $value . "<br />";
    }
}
```